# Outlook on Mac: how to use Ctrl-A and Ctrl-E for start and end of line?

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook

I am using MacOS. I am forced to use Outlook for email (couldn't find a decent replacement yet). For some reason, M$ decided it's a good idea to hard-code `Ctrl-A` for select all and `Ctrl-E` for nothing. Every other application with editing capability has those for START and END of line.

Is there a way to tweak this?

Comment: C-e C-n C-p all do nothing. Even worse, option-backspace consumes spaces sometimes, but other times it stops before a space, for unknown reasons. It feels patronizing at best.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, i have done a lot of research, but didn't find a useful methond. I'm afraid it is not available.

As i know, this [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/keyboard-shortcuts-for-outlook-3cdeb221-7ae5-4c1d-8c1d-9e63216c1efd#PickTab=macOS) describes the keyboard shortcuts in Outlook for Mac. In addition, we can only create other shortcuts manually. For more informarion, please refer to: [Create a custom keyboard shortcut for Office for Mac](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-custom-keyboard-shortcut-for-office-for-mac-6bbeb90e-96d9-4e03-b199-fc026ebdc321)